# Static and Dynamic Ground Difference in Daisy-Chain powering scheme

Tags: grounding

I am using a +24 V distribution bus to transmit power to 10 loads spread over a meter (e.g. each one at 0.1 m distance). The power distributed daisy-chain style using 2x10 flat cables (computer cable) for ease of assembly and because these cables are very low cost. The wires ares connected in parallel for sufficiently low resistance.

NOTE: Daisy-chain is a requirement for assembly purposes.

I also need to transmit a common control signal (on/off) to all the 10 loads. Due to the high current, there will be a ~1.5 V static ground shift between the most distal and proximal loads. So that means if I use a common driver to send a +5 V logic signal to them all the most distant one may suffer logic problems (or reduced margin). Add on top the inductance and it may problematic when the loads turn on off.

Here is my brainstorming for solutions:

1. Repeat the signal, in a daisy chain approach as the ground between adjacent loads is not that different
2. Use differential signaling (e.g. RS-485 style)
3. Use optocoupler on each load
4. Use a +24 V logic/control signal, so the ground bounce eats less margin

I concluded an optocoupler approach is the simplest, lowest cost solution. I welcome your input.

Comment: Yup, any of those answers will work. You could also use a current signal instead of a voltage signal. However, If you are dropping that much voltage down the chain I do hope your load variance down the chain is in spec.

Comment: A better solution would probably be to separate the control ground from the load ground. Then drive the load locally on each board through an opto-coupler. Or is that what you meant.

Comment: @Trevor  : Thanks for the feedback. Each load locally down-regulates to about +5V using a SMPS. The 24 V bus is to reduce the distribution currents to acceptable level. Yes I was planning a separate control ground and a logic signal to control an opto-coupler on each load.